# When or where did "sth" come to mean "something"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, ambiguity, non-native-english

This is not the same question as [What is meant by "sth"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/what-is-meant-by-sth) although one of it's answers is a partial answer to this question.

This question does not relate to "what does **sth** mean?" but those that it has that meaning for.

In [What is meant by "sth"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/what-is-meant-by-sth) user @jon-hanna explains that the abbreviation originated in dictionaries, guides, and reference books, misleading readers into thinking that such abbreviations are standard use.

This answers one meaning of the **where** part of the question, leaving open the **when** which @jon-hanna has not addressed, and where this has been observed.

---

I'm a native speaker, born and living in england, and widely read from modern books and many classics.

I've seen **sth** as an abbreviation of **something**, but only informally from those who have learned English as a second language.

I've seen this from Chinese and also those from eastern Europe.

I the late 1990's I asked one user where he learned the term and he reported that his language teacher taught that abbreviation as being current in the English speaking world.

When I first saw this on a computer forum I had to ask what it meant, as the obvious **sexually transmitted herpes** (derived from **STD**) did not fit the context.

So the questions are:

1. where and when did this abbreviation originate?
2. have you seen this used by native English speakers anywhere in the world? (particularly pre-internet age, ~1990)

Comment: I don't know why this question keeps coming up so often, but this abbreviation originated in dictionaries written by native English speakers for native English speakers, literally hundreds of years ago. Go grab any dictionary from that time. People in the Internet age are incredibly obsessed with recency illusions.

Comment: Reg Beat me to it, but you can't be an owner of a dictionary; abbreviations such as *sth*,  *adj*, *n*, and *obs* are commonly used. BUT, the question as to when it was first seen is not answered in the duplicate.

Comment: 1900 [French dictionary](https://books.google.it/books?id=lEgQAAAAYAAJ&q=sth+something&dq=sth+something&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI-oq2gK7RyAIVZ-9yCh0M3AAE) Looking for *sth* is proving fiendishly difficult because Google books interpret *sth* as meaning 5th :)

Comment: Maybe the answer to my question comes up a lot in related questions, but I don't find the question coming up a lot. Usually it is the meaning of **sth** which is not my question, my question is on who uses it and where it is used. Many questions here with the word(?) "sth" are using the word rather than referring to it.