# The usage of "conversion"

Tags: word-usage

In the [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/conversion), *conversion* means "the act or process of changing something from one form, use or system to another."

How to understand this "something"? If someone changed his behaviour, is it valid to say "the conversion of his act surprised me"?

Comment: The *sth* is an abbreviation for *something*. You convert something from one form, use, or system to another *something*. Form: You convert lead to gold. Use: You convert the use of the heel of a shoe to the use of a hammer. System: You convert a measurement in inches to a measurement in centimeters.

Comment: Related: [What is meant by "sth"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/what-is-meant-by-sth)

Comment: what I am saying is some intangible things like manner, tone. Can they be converted?@Kit @rajah9

Comment: Yes, if someone is loud and rude, his manner and tone might undergo a conversion, say, when speaking to his boss. King Lear says: "How, how, Cordelia! mend your speech a little, Lest it may mar your fortunes." (Act 1, Scene 1) He is asking her for a conversion of her manner and tone to something more ornate and loving (toward him).

Comment: Normally "conversion" would not be used in that sense.  When one speaks of "conversion" with regard to a person it generally reflects a major change in attitude/beliefs, as when someone is "converted" to a different religion.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker of English, if I heard someone say "the conversion of his act surprised me" I would be confused, so I wouldn't recommend using "conversion" like this. Conversion when applied to people tends to have a religious meaning, e.g. he converted to Roman Catholicism.

I also have a problem with "act" in this sentence because an "act" is a one time event but "behavior" is an ongoing pattern.  If you're talking about someone's behavior you can't use act as a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't common in everyday English speech to use *conversion* as a synonym for *change* in the sense of "difference." For example, we would be far less likely to say

> Everyone noticed the **conversion** in his behavior after the incident on the freeway.

than to say

> Everyone noticed the **change** in his behavior after the incident on the freeway.

or

> Everyone noticed the **difference** in his behavior after the incident on the freeway.

or perhaps

> Everyone noticed the **alteration** in his behavior after the incident on the freeway.

*Conversion* is much more likely to be used in connection with the event of switching from one state of action or belief to another than in connection with the resulting difference in behavior. So we might use *conversion* in a situation like this one:

> After his **conversion** to an alcohol-free lifestyle, we noticed a **change** [*not* "a conversion"] in his attitude toward school.

Answer (score 0):

> "the conversion of his act surprised me"

Technically this is incorrect to say since the original *act* was not *converted* so much as *replaced* with a different act. For example, say you have a cup of milk. Say then that you pour out the milk and fill the cup with orange juice. Was the milk converted to orange juice, or was the milk replaced with orange juice? While liquid water can be converted to steam, it would have to be replaced with oil.