# Meaning of S. TH

Tags: abbreviations

I'm working with an instructor and we have both searched for this answer, but have failed in finding it.

In language manuals, what does *s.th.* stand for?

Comment: Can you give an example? What is the page or paragraph where this occurs about?

Comment: It probably means something. (By that, I mean the literal word *something*.)

Comment: Yes. Also _sb_ for _somebody_. It's an indefinite, that's all.

Answer (score 22):

It's a different way (typically, [*sth*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19841/191178) is used) to abbreviate *something*:

> [image: Explanation of the abbreviations used in this Dictionary... s. th, signifies something.]
>
> <sub>From [A Dictionary of the Otchipwe Language, Explained in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=ntMzAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA309&lpg=PA309&dq=%22s.th.%22+something&source=bl&ots=DNd5ljNgTo&sig=_VwTk-RaTRpQqAUFfWrOl_oQbiU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjezLqDzdrPAhWJ8CYKHeXzBiI4ChDoAQhAMAc#v=onepage&q=%22s.th.%22%20something&f=false)</sub>

Comment: Is "Otchipwe" what we'd modernly spell "Ojibwe"?

Comment: @Marthaª [Yes](http://www.worldlanguage.com/Languages/OjibwaOtchipwe.htm). Not that it really matters, since I just wanted an example of s.th.

Comment: Of course it doesn't really matter, it's just strange that the accepted spelling has changed from unvoiced to voiced. I wonder which is more accurate?

Comment: @Marthaª, both are probably just as accurate, but "ojibwe" is more helpful in the Roman alphabet.  The sound /b/ in Ojibwe varies by dialect: some pronounce it /b/ and some pronounce it /p/, and in earlier times it was always pronounced /p/.  There's another consonant that's pronounced /pʰ/, like /p/ with a puff of air, so today /pʰ/ is spelled "p" and the other one is spelled "b".  (Same thing in Mandarin is (basically) why we have "Peking" and "Beijing".)