# 'I didn't know I needed' meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have seen this phrase in youtube comments:

`the *sth* I didn't know I needed`

Could you please explain what does it mean and in which cases should I use it?

Comment: *smtng* looks like a non-standard way of abbreviating _something._

Comment: see:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/what-is-meant-by-sth

Comment: The meaning of "something *I didn't know I needed*" is quite literal - it's something that you needed, but you didn't know you needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where a noun phrase is modified by a relative clause which it is not the subject of, the relative pronoun or relativiser ("who", "which", "that") is often omitted.

After verbs like "know", the "that" of an object clause is often omitted.

Here you have two "that"s omitted:

> The (something) [that] I didn't know [that] I needed.

Comment: This 'something' turned out to be very useful to you, but until you discovered it you had not felt the lack of it.